# captionsetup works for one table but not the other

Tags: tables, captions, margins, labels, leftmargin

I've adjusted my question below:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\restylefloat{table}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}

\shorttitle{Testing Tables}


\begin{document}

\section{B. Reported Rate Tables}\refstepcounter{section}\label{exp4_sec:report_tables}

\subsection{Raw Data}

\begin{table}[h!]
%\small % <-- may or may not be needed
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{12}{wc{0.7cm}} }
         \toprule
    Condition  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{18s} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{36s} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{54s} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{72s}  \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10} \cmidrule(l){11-13}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30\%} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{70\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{70\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30\%} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{70\%}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{30\%} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{70\%} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10} \cmidrule(l){11-13} 
                               \%     &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)} &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)} &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)} &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)} &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)}   \\
    
  \midrule
    Adapt  & 9(3)   &  56(4)  &  94(2) & 16(4) &  59(3) &  94(2) &  15(5) &  60(4)  &  92(3) & 19(4) &  61(3) &  90(3)\\
    Control  & 4(1)   &  52(3)  &  94(2) & 5(2) &  54(3) &  96(1) &  6(2) &  47(3)  &  94(2) & 6(1) &  50(3) &  96(1) \\
    Sig.  &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.089}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.360}           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.986}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.004\tabfnt{**}}   &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.250} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.331}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.085}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.003\tabfnt{**}}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.445}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.002\tabfnt{**}}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.008\tabfnt{**}}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.047\tabfnt{*}} \\ \midrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{Experiment 4: Average perceived percentage of movement in the adaptation direction and standard error of the adaptation and the control conditions for all subjects (n = 31), by adaptation time periods and level of actual percentage of movement in the adaptation direction.}
    \label{tab:exp4}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
        {\small
            \tabfnt{*}\textit{p} < .05., \tabfnt{**}\textit{p} < .01.
            , Tukey correction.
         }
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}



\subsection{Filtered Data}

\begin{table}[h!]
%\small % <-- may or may not be needed
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{12}{wc{0.75cm}} }
         \toprule
    Condition  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{18s} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{36s} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{54s} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{72s}  \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10} \cmidrule(l){11-13}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30\%} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{70\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{70\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30\%} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{70\%}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{30\%} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{70\%} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10} \cmidrule(l){11-13} 
                               \%     &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)} &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)} &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)} &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)} &  \emph{M(SE)}  &  \emph{M(SE)}   \\
    
  \midrule
    Adapt  & 10(2)   &  56(4)  &  91(2) & 17(5) &  61(3) &  88(3) &  20(5) &  64(4)  &  89(3) & 19(6) &  63(4) &  96(2)\\
    Control  & 6(2)   &  53(3)  &  92(2) & 6(2) &  52(4) &  93(2) &  6(2) &  44(4)  &  92(3) & 7(2) &  49(3) &  96(2) \\
    Sig.  &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.183}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.577}           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.672}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.013\tabfnt{*}}   &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.048\tabfnt{*}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.106}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.009\tabfnt{**}}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.001\tabfnt{**}}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.342}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.077\tabfnt{+}}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.027\tabfnt{*}}&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.000} \\ \midrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{Experiment 4: Average perceived percentage of movement in the adaptation direction and standard error of the adaptation and the control conditions for filtered subjects (n = 31), by adaptation time periods and level of actual percentage of movement in the adaptation direction.}
        \label{tab:exp4_filter}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
        {\small
          \tabfnt{+}\textit{p} < .08.,
            \tabfnt{*}\textit{p} < .05., \tabfnt{**}\textit{p} < .01.
            , Tukey correction.
         }
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here are what the modified tables look like:

[image]
[image]

The two tables were still not on the same page. I wonder if there is any way to make the two tables together (or at least not separate the table 2 title from table 2 so much)? Also, for the "%" line some "M(SE)"s were close, while others have more space. I wonder if it's possible to adjust this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ? What's the main document font size? How wide is the textblock (or, alternatively, how wide are the margins)? And how or where is `\tabfnt` defined?

Comment: Here are my answers: \documentclass[man]{apa7} . I guess it defines margins and \tabfnt. Here is my template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-and-sample-for-authoring-apa7-manuscripts/pvhtwcrvcmsp

Comment: @Lily Make your code compilable. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). For example, you need to add the necessary packages like `booktabs`, `threeparttables`, etc.

Comment: Hi @Imran , thank you for the suggestion. I just updated my question with MWE and made sure that the code could run on its own. Excuse me that I have to stick with the APA document class so I still included it here. Any suggestions in answering my questions then?

Comment: @Lily Some "M(SE)" are close where some have more because the columns have different width due to use of table notes in some columns. One solution may be using fixed width columns.

Comment: Thanks @Imran . I wonder if there are any suggestions to reduce the space between the two tables? Ideally, I'd like to fit the two tables into the same page.

Comment: @Lily From the width of your table, I don't think it's possible to fit them in a single page. But if you can put them in a single table environment (like subtable) and use a single caption (and probably subcaption) then it should be possible to fit them in the same page.